# Using a column that contains a frequency/weight/count in R

Tags: r

This is an easy question to ask, but a hard one to search for. Frequency is used all over the place. I tried a synonym (weight), but since `mtcars` is so widely used, I get a lot of false negatives as well. Same thing for counts.

I'm looking at `datasets::HairEyeColor`, partly reproduced here:

```
    Hair   Eye    Sex Freq
1  Black Brown   Male   32
2  Brown Brown   Male   53
3    Red Brown   Male   10
4  Blond Brown   Male    3
5  Black  Blue   Male   11
6  Brown  Blue   Male   50
7    Red  Blue   Male   10
8  Blond  Blue   Male   30
9  Black Hazel   Male   10
10 Brown Hazel   Male   25
.
.
.
```

I can across this when trying to show someone how to make a mosaic plot of any two of `Hair`, `Eye`, and `Gender`. On first read, I didn't see a way to specify a column to specify "this column represents 32 of the set members" but I didn't read too carefully.

I suppose I could reshape the data using `melt()` and `reshape()` every time I receive data with a frequency column, but that seems kind of drastic.

In other languages I know, I could add a parameter to the fitting function to let it know “there’s not just one row with this set of levels, there are *n* of them. So if I wanted to see a distribution, I might say
DISTR(Y=Hair, FREQ=freq)
...which would generate a histogram or density plot with *n* values per row

Alternately,
lm(hair ~ eye + sex, data = ‘HairEyeColor’, freq = ‘freq’)
Would fit a linear model with 32 replications if the first row rather than 1.

I’m asking about a way to use the 32 in the first row (for example) to tell the modeling or graphing function that there are 32 cases with this combination of levels, 53 with the combination in the second row, etc.

Surely this kind of data shows up a lot. I see it all the time, but there’s usually a way to say that this number specifies the frequency that this row represents in the actual data. Rather than a data table with 32 rows of Black, Brown, Male, there’s one row with frequency 32.

(No plyr please.)

Comment: What is exactly your question? Is it about reshaping from table to data.frame just like `ftable` examples?

Comment: *"Is there a standard R parameter I should look for that lets me use the data table as-is?"* Use it for what? Modeling? Plotting? something else? I guess the answer is no, because individual methods may have such parameters but there is not general parameter....

Comment: I’ll amend the question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Ok—I hope this helps. In SPSS, SAS, JMP, and others, when you ask for a plot or a model, there’s a way to specify a FREQ variable allowing for that row to be used multiple times. I thought there might be a command, or a small collection of commands, among the major packages that would let me do this. I can reshape the data, but I would’ve bet there was a direct way.

Comment: @JilberUrbina No, it’s about plotting or modeling without reshaping; using the data as-is, with a FREQ column, with the model/graph/whatever knowing that each row represented more than one data point.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a standard way to use this type of data across all of R.

Many of the basic modeling functions, e.g., `lm`, `glm`, `nls`, `loess`, and more from the `stats` package accept a `weights` argument that will meet your needs. `prop.test` accepts data in either format. But many other modeling functions do not, e.g., `knn`, `princomp`, and many others not in base R.

`barplot` accepts input in either format. `mosaicplot` expects input as an aggregated contingency table. Other types of plots would require more custom handling, because there are a lot of different things you could do with frequency.

Of course, anything not in base R is up to whoever writes it.

`ggplot2` (which is not base R) generally handles this really well, e.g., `geom_bar` will stack up values by default, or in the case of scatterplots you could map `size` or `color` or `alpha` to visually convey the intensity.

`randomForest` and `xgboost` do not accept weights

---

I will say that I very rarely find this to be a problem. I'd encourage you to ask specific questions about methods where it is causing you issues. I think `mosaicplot` is a bad example as it expects a contingency table, so the problem would be the opposite: using it with disaggregated data would require first aggregating it up to a frequency table.

Comment: That is a good point, but I couldn’t get a mosaic plot out of the mosaicplot() function using the frequency table data. I was going to disaggregate it into a long, one-row-per-case table, but I thought that there might be a way I could make the mosaic plot with the data as-is. As I’m typing this, I wonder if converting HairEyeColor from a data frame to something else would help. As it is, I can’t get mosaic to work, and before I started with the reshaping I thought there would be a weighting like in he examples you mentioned.

Comment: That is to say: I was trying to do a mosaic plot of Hair and Eye from HairEyeColor and couldn’t. Everything I tried resulted in an error—objects not found, or illegal use of $ in Hair$HairEyeColor since apparently Hair wasn’t atomic. Turns out HairEyeColor, from `datasets` is a table, not a data frame, so although mosaic(HairEyeColor) works, 2×2 subtables are hard to get out without a ton of work.

Comment: I mean, it seems like you have a specific issue with `mosaicplot`, but you are trying to ask an extremely broad and general question about using "modeling or graphing functions", of which R has *thousands*. I've answered your general question as best I can. If you want help with `mosaicplot` and the `HairEyeColor` data, I'd suggest asking a new question focused on that. I'm also confused by the data you show in your question... when I look at `datasets::HairEyeColor` I get a 4x4x2 array. Seems like you've already done some manipulation of the data that you don't show.

Comment: And there are also issues of conventions for data storage changing over time. `HairEyeColor` has probably been part of R for 20 years. These days, it would probably be encoded as you show it in the question, as a long data frame. There are plenty of other horrors in `datasets`, kept for historical reasons--just look at `anscombe`!

Comment: I’ve had the broad question in my mind for a while, and it was tonight’s mosaic plots that tipped me into asking if there was a general freq/weight argument that I didn’t know about. My experience here tells me that a question without specifics—specific code, data, etc., won’t get answered. Since I didn’t have another example prepared, I used this mosaic plot example since it was the one that really made me wonder. If I have a specific question about mosaic plots *of course* I’ll ask another question about it. This question was about freq variables, nothing more.

Comment: *"My experience here tells me that a question without specifics—specific code, data, etc., won’t get answered."* Did my best, but yeah. Stack Overflow culture focused on specific questions, with "Too Broad" and "Opinion Based" and "Unclear" as close reasons. I think much of that is that questions in those categories tend to better served by discussions than answers, and SO has chosen an answer-focused path. Other forums (RStudio community forums, Twitter, Reddit, mailing lists) will give a warmer reception for those questions.